# jQuery click() is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown from a tut a recently saw. It was designed to work with `hover()` but I want it on click event. When I change it like that it is not working anymore.

Here is it on JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Manny5980/bm0mmo0x/

P.S. Don't mind the irresponsiveness. I'll tidy up. :)

Comment: You can try this. 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.options').slideToggle(200);
    });
});

Comment: [**working solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/bm0mmo0x/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover could take two parameters while click could only take one.

Hover

```
$( ".a" ).hover(hoverIn(), hoverOut());
```

Click

```
$( ".a" ).click(whatHappensWhenYouClick());
```

This should show the dropdown menu but it won't pull it up, try using toggleClass() to toggle between the dropdown and pull up state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function(){
      $(this).children('.options').slideDown(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`.click()` accept one callback function, you have two of them. Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(
    function() {
      $(this).children('.options').slideToggle(200);
    }
  );
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bm0mmo0x/4/

Answer (score 0):

On click slideToggle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.options').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/bg-img.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D1DBBD;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #193441;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #91AA9D;
}

nav li ul {
  background-color: #91AA9D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 140px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #193441;
  color: black;
}


nav li li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav li li ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:200px;
  margin:0;
}

nav a {
  line-height:40px;
  padding:0 12px;
  margin:0 12px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
}

nav li li a {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #193441;
  margin:0 10px;
  padding:0;
}
nav li li:last-child a {border-bottom:none;}

.options {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Клавиатури</a>
        <ul class="options">
          <li><a href="#">SteelSeries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Razer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Logitech</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hama</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Мишки</a></li>
```

If you need for multiple dropdown you can add this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown').children('.options').slideUp(200);
      $(this).children('.options').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/bg-img.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D1DBBD;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #193441;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #91AA9D;
}

nav li ul {
  background-color: #91AA9D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 140px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #193441;
  color: black;
}


nav li li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav li li ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:200px;
  margin:0;
}

nav a {
  line-height:40px;
  padding:0 12px;
  margin:0 12px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
}

nav li li a {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #193441;
  margin:0 10px;
  padding:0;
}
nav li li:last-child a {border-bottom:none;}

.options {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Клавиатури</a>
        <ul class="options">
          <li><a href="#">SteelSeries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Razer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Logitech</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hama</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Мишки</a>
        <ul class="options">
          <li><a href="#">SteelSeries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Razer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Logitech</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hama</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Слушалки</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Падове</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Gaming Packs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `click` use `on` method that is more efficient and you can pass any event handler through `on` method. See the snippet.

You could use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').on('click', function(){
    $(this).children('.options').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bm0mmo0x/6/